# How to activate an active environment within a certain folder in Julia

Tags: julia, environment, working-directory

After reading [Pkg](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/#Pkg-1) I can't figure out how to implement an active environment within a certain folder (something like Open Project in New Session by RStudio).
It's possible?
Is there any other document about it?
Please instruct me how to do it!

Comment: The full documentation of Pkg is at https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/, as mentioned on top of the page you linked to. You should try reading that one first, especially the section "Working with Environments".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In julia you can use the question mark `?` to access [the help mode of the REPL](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/REPL/#Help-mode-1). Then you can ask for help on using Pkg.activate if you do:

```
julia> using Pkg
```

and then you type

```
?Pkg.activate
```

(you will see some examples:)

```
  Pkg.activate()
  Pkg.activate("local/path")
  Pkg.activate("MyDependency")
```

This works if you did the "using" step first.

But you can activate your environment from the Pkg mode in the REPL (accessed by typing `]` from the REPL) as well by typing

```
] activate local/path/to/your/environment
```

Assuming that your environment is at the path "local/path/to/your/environment"

You can see this help by typing

```
julia> ]? activate
```

on your REPL

Answer (score 1):

I use https://direnv.net and create a `.envrc` file with this in it:

```
export JULIA_PROJECT=@.
```

The first time you use it you have to do `direnv allow` and after that whenever you're in that directory your environment is modified so that Julia uses it as your active project. You can also add other useful environment variables in there.